# why python interpreter does not interpret the rest of the code

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me if there's something wrong with my code?

```py
import time
t = time.strftime("%H")
print(t)

if t > 0 and t < 12:
    print("Good Morning")
elif t >= 12 and t < 18:
    print("Good Afternoon")
if t >= 18 and t < 0:
    print("Good Night")
```

When I ran this code [on replit.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH196.png), it printed the hour as 16 and printed "Good Afternoon" as intended.

When I ran this code [inside VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B6LO.png)
(Interpreter version: 3.11.4 64bit (Microsoft Store)), it printed the hour as 22, but it didn't print any message.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Regarding your error: It seems that in one image, the code takes the second branch (`t = 16`), and in one, you want it to take the third branch (`t = 22`). However, the condition `t >= 18 and t < 0` is always false, regardless of the value of `t`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `t >= 18 and t < 0` can never be true, since those two things can't both be true at once. You probably meant `or` instead of `and`.

Also, if you're seeing those different hour results around the same time, it's possible that Replit is executing your code on a server which is in a different timezone.

Comment: No, `or` wouldn't fit since hour of a day cannot be negative.

Comment: @InSync That seems orthogonal to me. Yes, I too suspected that the second half of that `or` will never be true, so just deleting the `and t < 0` is arguably a better fit than changing it to `or t < 0`. But the asker can learn/decide that later. Meanwhile, even if the second condition is redundant, to me it seems clear that they *intended* an `or` of those two conditions, and that their question was at the level of misunderstanding why/how their intent was mistranslating to code.

Answer (score 0):

The value of t is 22 and in your code no statement matching for your condition. Your code is correct!

Comment: How are you saying that his code is not correct ? his code is correct only but the value what he expecting for his input is wrong!

Comment: What I'm saying is, the condition `t >= 18 and t < 0` is nonsense because it can never be true. OP has a logic error.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, and I even thought about commenting to defend your use of "correct", which I thought you were using in a funny, ironic way, to tell the asker "your code is faithfully/'correctly' behaving as-written (so reconsider what you wrote)". But when trying to be helpful to newbie coders, consider that when someone says that code they wrote is not doing what they intended it to do, that code cannot be correct by common useful definitions of correct such as "works as intended".

Comment: Similarly, as @wjandrea said, when someone does something like a compound condition where the two halves of the condition cancel each other out, making the condition equivalent to either a hard-coded true or a hard-coded false (creating unconditional code or dead code that looks conditional at a glance based on the shape/structure/syntax), then that's also very clearly not correct (by other common useful meanings of "correct" such as "one of the good-enough ways to achieve the intended goals", "not needing any correction", etc etc etc).